# Согласуется ли "кто-то" со множественным числом?

Tags: согласование

*"Фёдоров понимал, что в помощи нуждаются не кто-то иные, а именно Петровы".*

Как вообще правильно это предложение согласовать? Если *"не кто-то иной"*, то надо и *"нуждаются"* ставить в ед. ч., значит: *"нуждается не кто-то иной, а именно Петровы"* = *"нуждается... Петровы"*: рассогласование.

Comment: Надо так: *не кто иные, как Петровы*.

Comment: Нет. Оборот "не кто иной, как..." не синонимичен обороту "не кто-то иной, а..."

Comment: Ну раз вы именно тот хотите, то: *не кто-то другой/иной, а именно Петровы*. *Не кто-то иные* — это не по-русски.